# UIPicker font size for a certain column and row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel, uipickerview

I'm looking to change the font size of a certain column and row in a UIPicker. Basically there's too much text that runs off the view and I'd like to size just that particular row in the 2nd column down so it fits?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to customize label font size, implement delegate method called :

`-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;`

to return a well configured `UILabel` (you can change `font` property or set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property to `YES`).

Comment: thanks. I just found this, which is useful too: http://alisothegeek.com/2009/07/custom-uipickerview-text-formatting/