# Change Picker View Text Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Have been searching around and can't find the answer to this. I'm just wondering how to change the color of the font for each individual line of a picker. Is this even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Here are a few links to get you started:

- [UIPicker font size for a certain column and row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829132/uipicker-font-size-for-a-certain-column-and-row)
- http://alisothegeek.com/2009/07/custom-uipickerview-text-formatting/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate